# How do I return a number from a postgreSQL query from inside Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have been looking for this answer for a couple days now.  I have to be missing something obvious.  I have a query in Node.js as shown below.  I have been working with the results, but I can only view it with console.log.  Any attempt to put the value in a variable or otherwise access it has not worked.

```js
   const {Client} = require('pg');

const client = new Client ({
  user: 'pi',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'Farm2021',
  password: 'password',
  port:5432
})



function updateRadon(){
  client.connect();
  const query = {
    text:'select radon from data where month=2 and day=8 and hour = 16 and radon>0;',
    rowMode: 'array'
  }
  var testObject = client.query(query, (err,res) =>{
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    testObject = res.row.prototype;
    console.log(res);
    client.end();
    return testObject;
  });
  console.log(testObject);
};

updateRadon();
```

Here is a sample of the output I get:

```
undefined Result {   command: 'SELECT',   rowCount: 1,   oid: null,   rows: [ [ 23 ] ],   fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'radon',
      tableID: 16464,
      columnID: 16,
      dataTypeID: 21,
      dataTypeSize: 2,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    }   ],   _parsers: [ [Function: parseInteger] ],   _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}   },   RowCtor: null,   rowAsArray: true,   parseRow: [Function: _parseRowAsArray] }
```

How can I extract the useful value from this is the value of rows as a number (23) or something I can convert to a number.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The array with all the rows returned from the SELECT is `res.rows`: only one row was returned, so `res.rows` is an array of length 1. `23` is the value of the column `radon` (that is the only column in your SELECT).